# Convert router configuration file to csv with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a configuration file with repeating groups of lines (but different number of lines in a group) that I want to combine to single csv lines for easier importing to a database. (Database structure is flexible).

```
# Example: 
    lag 1
        description "LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2"
        port 1/2/1 
        port 1/2/2 
        port 3/2/3 
        lacp active administrative-key 32770
    exit
    lag 10
        description "REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0"
        port 4/1/1 
        port 5/1/1
        lacp active administrative-key 32771
    exit
    lag 11
        description "REMOVED-LAG-11-4.4.4.4"
        port 5/1/2 
        lacp active administrative-key 32772
    exit
```

I ultimately need to end up with comma-separated lines for each block between "lag" and "exit", like this:

```
1,"LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,1/2/3
1,"LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,1/2/2
1,"LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,3/2/3 
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",32771,4/1/1
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",32771,5/1/1
11,"REMOVED-LAG-11-4.4.4.4",32772,5/1/2
```

Then I would import to a table like this:

```
lag-id | description | key | port
```

I've tried various awk one-liners that I found here, such as:

```
awk -v RS="lag" 'NR>1{$1=$1; print RS, $0}'
```

but that seems to compress the lines vertically, so i end up with

```
 exit 3/2/3  "LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2"
 exit 4/2/3  "LAG 10 GOES TO LAG-3"
 exit 4/1/1  "LAG 11 GOES TO LAG-21"
```

EDIT: Updated config slightly, description may have LAG-x numbers twice.
EDIT 2: Updated adding lacp values to get admin key to each csv line.

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then

Comment: I've tried 
`awk -v RS="lag" 'NR>1{$1=$1; print RS, $0}'`
but that seems to compress the lines vertically, so i end up with
`exit 3/2/3  "LAG 11 GOES TO D"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
  sub(/^ +/,"")
}
/lag/{
  ind=$2
  next
} 
/description/ && match($0,/\".*\"/){ 
 des=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
 next
}
/port/{
 print ind,des,$2
}
'  Input_file
```

In case your strings may be either capital or small letter or of mix then you could add a `BEGIN` section with `IGNORECASE=1` in above code and it should match strings in any case then.

Explaination:  Following is only for explanation purposes, refer complete code above please.

`-v OFS=","` setting output field separator as comma for all lines.

`gsub(/\r/,"")` globally substituting \r control m characters with NULL as per OP's comment they were there.

`sub(/^ +/,"")` Substituting initial space of line with NULL here.

`/lag/{Ind=$2;next}` searching line which had string lag in it and creating variable Ind whose value is $2 next will skip all further statements from here onwards.

`/description...../` looking for line which has string description in it and then using match function of awk to look for regex from `"` till `"` in same line. Saving this matched regex value in variable named desc, next will skip all further statements from here.

`/port/...` looking for line which has string port in it and then printing value of ind,des,$2 here as per OP's requirement.

Comment: That gets me very close! I can't get the result to paste in this comment very well.

Comment: I tried on my test config above, but my production config it does not work. I get `,1/2/1ag 1
,1/2/2ag 1
,3/2/3ag 1
,2/2/1ag 2
,2/2/2ag 2
,4/2/3ag 2
,4/1/1ag 10
,5/1/2ag 11
,5/1/1ag 12
,4/1/2ag 13
`

Comment: the case is correct. It has something to do with whitespace characters. I can get it to work if I copy my config out and paste it into a new file with vi, but the original text does not work. Still looking on my end.

Comment: Also, I only see lag, lag  and port, not description: 

1,     lag 1,     port 1/2/1... etc.

Comment: @Danny Z, Chech now my updated code and let me know, I apologies I am on mobile and didn't test code written it there, we should be good here.

Comment: I think you got it! Testing more examples here now.

Comment: One thing, it works only if my line endings are \n, but not if they are \r\n. I am using `sed 's/\r$//'` to first remove the \r

Comment: can you explain a little bit of what this is doing? I am not familiar with some of this, though I do use awk from time to time.

Comment: @Danny Z, please do give me 5 mins, will Add full explanation for solution.

Comment: @Danny Z, I have added explanation for code now, sorry from mobile couldn't do much formatting. Feel free to have any queries o ln same, cheers.

Comment: @Danny Z, I added part how to remove control M characters too in my solution now, any questions are welcome.

Comment: Very helpful. I have added a few new lines to see how it works. Your explanation of what is happening was useful.  `/lacp/{lacp=$2;key=$4;next}` is working well with my updated sample file, except I think it is printing the wrong value because port appears before the lacp line in the file.

Comment: @Danny Z, cool, if this is for your new question you could check out my new answer. But trust me coding and typing on mobile is very difficult :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    tag = $1
    sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/,"")
    vals[++numVals] = $0
}
tag == "exit" {
    for (valNr=3; valNr<numVals; valNr++) {
        print vals[1], vals[2], vals[valNr]
    }
    numVals = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1,"LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2",1/2/1
1,"LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2",1/2/2
1,"LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2",3/2/3
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",4/1/1
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",5/1/1
11,"REMOVED-LAG-11-4.4.4.4",5/1/2
```

Comment: I like how your solution is a file that can be read more easily. How would I go about adding a new field? For instance if another line existed below the "port" lines, and I wanted to include that in the csv output?

Comment: Any of the solutions can be stored in a file and executed with `awk -f file` or can be done on the command line with `awk 'script'`. For adding a new value, it depends how you'd want it to appear in the CSV output. The main point of my script is to avoid coupling the code to the data by testing values in the data (lag, description, port) and instead just map locations of values in the input to locations in the output based on the one data value that indicates the end of each record - "exit", so we'd have to see the data to know how that approach would be applied given some different mapping.

Comment: If we added `lacp active administrative-key 32770 ` where 32770 is some integer, and this line always followed the last 'port' entry. I guess it would help to understand what part of your script is handling the repeated 'port' entries, and what part is handling the positioning of the lag number and description field. This would help me adapt it for other uses down the road.

Comment: Again, it depends how you'd want that displayed in the CSV. Update your question to show concise, testable sample input/output like you have now but with that field added and I'll take a look.

Comment: Never, mind, I see you already accepted a different answer. Feel free to post a new question with that modified input/output if you like or just follow up with the poster of your accepted answer for enhancements to this one.

Comment: Will post again. Sorry for the confusion. I am new to asking on stack. You have been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk:

```
awk '$1~/lag/{l=$2;next}
     $1~/description/{d=substr($0,index($0,"\""));next}
     $1~/port/{print l,d,$2}
' OFS=, file
```

The 2 first statements get the second field into `l` and `d` variable respectively for both `lag` and `description` keywords.

The last statement prints the 2 variables and the second field associated to `port` keyword.

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so obfuscates your code.