# Convert section of router configuration to csv file with bash

Tags: bash, awk, config

Similar to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58202817/1745001), but additional items added to the config file sample.

I have a configuration file with repeating groups of lines (but different number of lines in a group) that I want to combine to single csv lines for easier importing to a database. (Database structure is flexible).

```
# Example: 
    lag 1
        description "LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2"
        port 1/2/1 
        port 1/2/2 
        port 3/2/3 
        lacp active administrative-key 32770
    exit
    lag 10
        description "REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0"
        port 4/1/1 
        port 5/1/1
        lacp active administrative-key 32771
    exit
    lag 11
        description "REMOVED-LAG-11-4.4.4.4"
        port 5/1/2 
        lacp active administrative-key 32772
    exit
```

I ultimately need to end up with comma-separated lines for each block between "lag" and "exit", like this:

```
1,"LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,1/2/3
1,"LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,1/2/2
1,"LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,3/2/3 
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",32771,4/1/1
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",32771,5/1/1
11,"REMOVED-LAG-11-4.4.4.4",32772,5/1/2
```

Then I would import to a table like this:

```
lag-id | description | key | port
```

I've tried various awk one-liners that I found here, such as:

```
awk -v RS="lag" 'NR>1{$1=$1; print RS, $0}'
```

but that seems to compress the lines vertically, so i end up with

```
 exit 3/2/3  "LAG 1 GOES TO LAG-2"
 exit 4/2/3  "LAG 10 GOES TO LAG-3"
 exit 4/1/1  "LAG 11 GOES TO LAG-21"
```

Comment: could you please check mine answer once and let me know if this was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    tag = $1
    val = ( match($0,/"[^"]*"/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : $NF )

    if ( tag == "port" ) {
        ports[++numPorts] = val
    }
    else {
        vals[++numVals] = val
    }
}

tag == "exit" {
    for (portNr=1; portNr<=numPorts; portNr++) {
        for (valNr=1; valNr<numVals; valNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[valNr], OFS
        }
        print ports[portNr]
    }
    numPorts = numVals = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1,"LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,1/2/1
1,"LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,1/2/2
1,"LAG-1 GOES TO LAG-2",32770,3/2/3
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",32771,4/1/1
10,"REMOVED-LAG-10-0.0.0.0",32771,5/1/1
11,"REMOVED-LAG-11-4.4.4.4",32772,5/1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.(since I have written this on mobile so couldn't test it but should work)

```
awk -v OFS=","  '
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
  sub(/^ +/,"")
}
/lag/{
  ind=$2
  next
}
/description/ && match($0,/\".*\"/){ 
 desc=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
 next
}
/port/{
 a[++count]=$2
 next
}
/lacp active/{
 for(j=1;j<=count;j++){
   print Ind,desc,$NF,a[j]
 }
 count=""
 delete a
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Danny Z, could you please check this answer once and let me know if this is helpful?